# Is it incorrect to answer a question when it doesn't satisy the specific problem that the asker has but is generally right?

Tags: discussion

I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34998848/3664835) to the question [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3664835).

The question details deal with jQuery's `ajax`; while my answer deals with what the question title itself asks for.

Other answers talk about generally accepted solutions to the problem and they are good in most cases. I have given a solution that is useful in some situations, and is an approach that is usually not used.

However, I've been down voted without any comments. So, I was wondering if I should have answered the question elsewhere (where the question details don't deal with a specific library/function)!

Comment: You are worried about a single downvote? Due to the meta effect you may get a few more by posting here.

Comment: According to the SO "quality" standards: If your post is an attempt to answer the question, no matter how bad the attempt is, then it's an acceptable answer. The downside is of course, as observed, the down-votes.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I'm not worried about down votes; I'm just wondering if my answer belongs elsewhere!

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - Thanks for clearing that.

Comment: That question has been around for some time, has tons of views, and it already has 38 answers posted to it, some of them highly upvoted.  Did your answer genuinely contribute anything new?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Yes, this method isn't mentioned in any other answer and does something that most other answers claim is not possible!

Answer (score 8):

There is an infinity of things that are "generally right" (as in, technically correct information) but don't answer the *question being asked*. You should make sure that the answers you post are actually answering the question being asked, not just providing related information. If there appears to be a disconnect between the title and question body, consider commenting to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer looks technically accurate, but at the end of the day, you didn't answer the actual content of the question. If you had e.g. continued on and shown how to solve the OPs problem using Fiber, then your answer would be more relevant, and maybe worth upvoting.

People googling how to solve the same problem will 99.99% of the time read the question first (not just the title), then check the answers to see how it solves that question, then apply it to their own situation. Your answer isn't directly connected to the question so breaks their line of thought while they try to link what you are saying to the current code in mind (the OPs question).

Comment: When I searched for "how to return a value from an asynchronous function" that question was the first result. While OP's problem is with one specific function, the same question arises everywhere in node js and generally in javascript. I was trying to answer it in such a way that it is applicable to all node js applications and not just the one OP faced.